# Calling a vector of function pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I am trying to use vector of function pointer in C++ which belongs to one class and being called in another class. For example: In class BoundaryCondition (file BoundaryCondition.h), I initialize the function pointer as:

```
class BoundaryConditions{

public:
// Constructor function
BoundaryConditions(int id = 0);             
vector <void (BoundaryConditions::*) (Face &, int, int)> func2bcond;                

void fixedValue(Face &face, int id, int rkStep);
// and other functions with similar definition as fixedValue
}
```

In another class (DG.h), I initialize an array of BoundaryCondition instance, something like

```
BoundaryCondition *bcond;
```

and assign memory to bcond variable using new (in file DG.cpp). For each bcond[i] instance, I need to assign memory to function pointer as:

```
this->bcond[i].func2bcond.resize(totNoOfVariable);
```

I am using resize instead of pushback as file reading may not be in the required order. Next, I am assigning function to this function pointer (again in DG.cpp) as per my boundary condition file:

```
bcond[i].func2bcond[j] = (&BoundaryConditions::fixedValue);
```

The code compiles alright till this point. I am getting error when I try to call these functions. I call this in DG.cpp. The code is as follows:

```
(bcond[i].*func2bond[j])(f,1,2);
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
 error: 'func2bcond' was not declared in this scope
```

I am quite sure it is only matter of position of * or the brackets, but I am stuck here and I did not get any specific solved post on stackoverflow.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It should be `(*(bcond[i].func2bond[j]))(f,1,2);`

Comment: Alternatively, **std::invoke** could also be used [std::invoke Ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke)

Comment: First of, please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
Second, using naked C arrays to store data is a bad idea in modern C++, there are alternatives that save you from tracking lots of nasty bugs. Why not use a `std::vector<BoundaryCondition>` instead of an array?
Third, `fixedValue` is a member function. If you want to store a pointer to it, you must also say, which object the function should be called upon: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members. You can achieve this using `std::bind` or - better - a lambda expression.

Comment: "I initialize an array of BoundaryCondition instance, something like: BoundaryCondition *bcond;" -- this does not initialize anything

Comment: You have pointer to member function, so you need to have pointer to object for which you are calling these functions: `(&bcond[i] ->* (bcond[i].func2bcond[j]) )(f,1,2);` or `(bcond[i] .* (bcond[i].func2bcond[j]) )(f,1,2);`.

Comment: You should use a `std::function` instead of a C function pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer on method requires instance when called, so your code might look like:

```
(bcond[i].*(bcond[i].func2bond[j]))(f, 1, 2);
```

or, splitting expression:

```
auto methodPtr = bcond[i].func2bond[j]; // auto is `void (BoundaryConditions::*) (Face &, int, int)`
(bcond[i].*methodPtr)(f, 1, 2);
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks mate! However, I wonder why exactly does this (writing bcond twice) work? Can you explain this in detail.

Comment: I hoped than second snippet was clear enough in that regards:/ You basically can see `void (C::*m)()` as `void (*f)(C&)` (the extra `this` in method call). You need `bcond` twice as method pointer is stored in it, and you want to apply the method to instance `bcond[i]`.you might even repeat it more if extra argument were also members: `(bcond[i].*methodPtr)(bcond[i].face, bcond[i].id, bcond[i].rkStep);`.